# Quantile of the interval in r

Tags: r, quantile

We have the following vector:

```
BMI <- c( 24.00568, 46.76243, 23.34254, 47.26230, 14.73006, 14.07006, 
                                18.44512, 15.06024, 21.84091, 38.34783)
```

I want to know, which quantile is the value 25 and higher.

How can I do it in r?I know, it should be connected with the function `quantile`, but i can't figure out the solution.

Comment: so `quantile(BMI) > 25`?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the empirical cumulative distribution function `ecdf()`.

```
ecdf(BMI)(25)
```

Answer (score 2):

This just is the simple average of the number of elements below 25:

```
mean(BMI<25)
```